# facebook automatically uses user logged in facebook app to authentificate

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic3, facebook-javascript-sdk, angular5

i am developping an app using ionic cordova angluar 5. I tried to add facebook api and it works.
unfortunately, facebook api uses automatically the users logged in facebook app to authentificate/register, meanwhile i am looking for a way that give the right to the user to choose which account he wants to log in with.

For exemple, in the image below i use google api. Each time that the user try to authentificate/register a list of available account is shown and the user choose one of those account to authentificate/register.
I want to implement the same thing using facebook api, For the moment each time the user tries to authentificate, facebook api uses automatically the account logged in facebook app. Below i add the facebook api login function. Please help me find what i am doing wrong

[image]

This is the function that  written with angular 5.

```
  this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status === "connected") {

      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      //alert("good" + res.toString())
      this.getUserDetail(res);
    } else {
     // alert("bad" + res.toString())
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  }).catch();
```

Comment: Talking specifically about android, it doesn't allow you to add multiple accounts for different apps except google. Hence if user has added more than one account he will be given list of added accounts to choose the account he wants to use but since he can't have more than one account of facebook giving the option to choose doesn't make sense

Comment: In some apps in android like AIRBNB it gives you the hand to choose between mutliple account

Comment: then may be this limitation is imposed by facebook it self to not allow users to add more than one account since it only maintains one session in android

Comment: then, is there a way to at least offer the user the choice to authentificate each time without using the default session

Comment: this answer may be has the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19611360/975932, you will probably need to delete the permissions first in case user has already granted them to your app

Comment: deleting the user permission will not force the authentification each time. it will keep using the default facebook session and go directly to the permission page without authentification.

Comment: I am actualy looking for a way to force the user to choose to connect with his default account or to connect with another account